# Iscohedron Challenge

Tags: geometry

The 20 triangles shown below:

can be folded to form a regular icosahedron.[image]

In each of the faces,a number from 1 to 20 is to be written without any repeating. A pair of consecutive numbers must be written on faces sharing an edge, and 1 and 20 must also be on faces sharing an edge as well.

Comment: This is pretty easy if you have the icosahedron in front of you; it's only hard to do it on that net because of the random way the net is cut up.

Comment: I suggest drawing lines between edges wich will coincide in the actual model to get an overview of the adjacency.

Comment: This is equivalent to the [Icosian game](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IcosianGame.html). i.e finding a [Hamiltonian cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html) on a dodecahedron, the dual polyhedron for icosahedron.

Comment: @mathmaniac In case you're only interested in a solution, I've added one to my answer.

Comment: This question comes from the current USAMTS Round Two problem set ([problem 1](http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_2.pdf)). This question will remain locked until after the submission deadline of 8 Dec 2014.

Answer (score 2):

The red lines connect identified edges. This should help you easily filling the net by viewing it as a graph with the nodes corresponding to faces and the edges corresponding to adjacency (i.e. common edge or red line) and then finding a hamiltonian cycle such that the $i$-th visited node has number $i$ assigned to it (so you must start next to the $2$ and then visit the $2$, then place $3$ etc.
[image]

Here is a solution I came up with simply following the leads:
[image]

Comment: There is only one way $3,4,5$ can fit.  This forces the positioning of $1, 7, 16$ which then forces $8, 13, 20$  and so $9, 10, 11, 12$ and so $17, 18, 19$.  So done.

Comment: @Henry Not sure how you approached it since my $\{1,8,7\}$ could also be $\{3,4,5\}$ in order and not mess things up...

Comment: I tried the other way round and got stuck (perhaps mistakenly)

Comment: It was the same as AlexR's second diagram (without the red lines)

Comment: @mathmaniac The main job is to actually figure out where those red lines point to. If you want me to elaborate on that, please tell me.